# Copy constructor with arguments from another class

Tags: c++, arduino

I try to copy a constructor from another class. The two classes are in the same file. The error I currently get is:

> error: no matching function for call to B::B(A&)

A snippet from the main file:

```
#include "file.h"
// create the objects
A object1(1000000, 5);
B object2(object1);
```

A snippet from file.cpp:

```
class A {
public:
    A::A(uint32_t one, uint32_t two) { }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    B::B(const B &copy) : A(copy) { }
 }

};
```

A snippet from the header file file.

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B(const B&);
```

I tried to make the code as easy as possible for stackoverflow. Can someone please explain what is wrong here?

Comment: Don't redefine the *class* in the source file.

Comment: edit #include, wrong copy paste in here :)

Comment: And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you familiar with the meaning of a "*is-a*" relationship? Is it symmetric?

Comment: Which constructor should be called for `A(copy)`? Also as the error says you don't have a constructor that takes a `A` as parameter

Comment: "no matching function for call to B::B(A&)" means you are calling B constructor with an A object, and you have not provided that constructor in B.

Comment: Since `A` isn't a `B`, you need a *conversion* constructor of `B` that accepts the `A` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your B::B(const B&) expects a reference to a const B, but you're providing an instance of an A. It doesn't matter that B derives from A; even though every B is-a A, the reverse is not true. In fact, object1 is-a A, but is-not-a B.

To clarify some more: if you want B to be constructible from an A, you will need to provide a constructor that takes an A, like: `B::B(const A& copyA): A(copyA) {}`

Comment: Note that `B::B(const A& copyA)` **is not** a *copy constructor* of `B`, but it does *use* the copy constructor of `A`

Comment: Indeed. It would make B constructible from A, but would not itself be a "copy constructor."

Comment: I Had to Change "B::B(const B& copyA): A(copyA)" to indeed "B::B(const A& copyA): A(copyA)"

Answer (score 2):

Liskov substitution principle wiki page says:

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating
>   that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of
>   type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type
>   T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering
>   any of the desirable properties of the program (correctness, task
>   performed, etc.).

You can use objects of B instead of A but not reverse.